# Poisson Random Variable Question

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

> A radioactive source emits certain particles with a Poisson distribution. The probability of no particle emissions during an hour of observation is $0.4$. What is the probability that the first recorded emission happens within the first $40$ to $60$ minutes?

I'm given that $\lambda = \dfrac{ \ln 2.5}{ 60 }$

I'm also given the answer of $0.1429$ but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Okay I'll be sure to do that next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the Poisson distribution's rate parameter $\lambda$ from $\exp (-60\lambda)=0.4$ (taking one minute as our unit of time). The time to the first recorded emission is then exponentially distributed with this rate parameter, so the probability of it taking $40$ to $60$ minutes is $\exp (-40\lambda)-\exp (-60\lambda)=0.4^{2/3}-0.4$, which as required is $0.1429$.

Answer (score 0):

Have you come across the exponential distribution before? The probability you are after is $\int_{40} ^{60} λe^{-λx} dx=0.1429$.

Comment: I haven't come across it yet

Comment: Sorry, actually I have. I just found it buried in my notes.